# Kafka spring boot get information from metadata provided by kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, monitoring

I have a specific case that need to get the concrete timestamp of some consumer group disconnection from specific topic. Does Kafka provides a way to get this metadata as notification?
Thanks in advance

After some research I realized that kafka does not provide the technique to get notifications about it's consumers. I want to know maybe someone know a tricky way to figure out the timestamp of consumer disconnection from specific topic. Disconnection information need to be realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using [spring-kafka](/questions/tagged/spring-kafka). Try to add listeners on Consumer / Container Idle or Stopped events. You can call `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the method bodies for timestamps.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#events

Comment: Thank you for answer, but my case a little bit complicated. I have one kafka broker, and x count of consumer groups subscribed to one topic. From another microservice (consumer) I want to get information about disconnection of even one consumer group from that topic.

Comment: You can use `onPartitionsRevoked` Java API for any set of topic partitions, regardless of number of consumer groups. [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#rebalance-listeners). But you need to add that to each consumer client. As you'd said you discovered, Kafka itself will not send any such event on its own; the brokers are dumb in that way.